# Only 4 cores showing up in task manager

Tags: windows-8, cpu, task-manager, cpu-cores

For some reason only 4 cores are showing up in task manager I have tried everything(almost)

> - setting and unchecking number of cores in msconfig did not work
> - using easy BCD did not work
> - reinstalling OS on fresh partition did not work.
> - setting number of cores on BIOS did not work

I dont know what to do

system specs:
AMD FX 8150 eight core processor
os windows 8 enterprise

[image: cpuz specs]

Comment: Get a copy of CPU-z and please post a screenshot confirming that you do actually have that model of processor. http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: cpuz specs http://tinypic.com/r/2h5lklz/5

Comment: Check here. http://www.eightforums.com/drivers-hardware/11548-windows-8-not-using-all-8-cores-fx-8120-a-2.html

Comment: @KikBm Try right-clicking on the CPU graph and selecting "Change graph to logical processors".

Comment: Louis, shouldn't that be the answer? Because currently you posted it as comment but I would suggest it as right answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable graphing of logical processors. Right click **CPU**, and choose **"Change Graph to > Logical Processors"**. This should allow you to see all 8 cores (This is the process I took to see all cores on my similar AMD chip, so it should work for you).